# Centos7 Enable SSL - Connection Timeout

Tags: apache, ssl, centos7

I followed this doc here to enable SSL on a VM box - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7

only now when I try to visit my site I get a connection timed out - so something isn't configured correctly - I can't figure out what it is.

```
apachectl configtest
OK
```

/httpd/error_log doesn't show anything either

I've also verified and even changed for the hell of it my /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf but still the same issue persists.

Thoughts or help on what to check?

Comment: Is 443 port is opened or allowed by firewall?

Comment: ^^ And is Apache listening on port 443  `sudo a2enmod ssl`

Comment: a2enmod: command not found

Comment: LISTEN      0      128                                                             :::443                                                                         :::*

tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      7911/httpd

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a firewall ingress issue - resolved by allowing that access.